# Simulated annealing fit in Python

Tags: python, scipy, data-fitting, simulated-annealing

I am trying to getting familiar with the non linear fitting procedure: dual-annealing. To do so I generated some synthetic data and try to fit over them a basic Furth formula, see the code below:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import savetxt
from numpy import genfromtxt
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from lmfit import Minimizer, Parameters, report_fit
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing
```

```
def Furth(A,B, a, x):
    model = A*x + B * (np.exp(-a*x)-1) 
    return model
```

generating synthetic data:

```
x = np.arange(200)*0.5
x = x[1:]
A =1.88
B = 2.35
a = 5602
y = Furth(A,B,a,x) + np.random.randn(x.size)
```

Defining the function to fit:

```
def fit_msd2(params, x, data):
    A = params['A']
    B = params['B']
    c = params['c']

    model = A*x + B * (np.exp(-c*x)-1) 
    return model - data
```

```
params = Parameters()
params.add('A',   min=0, max = 100000)
params.add('B',   min=-100, max = 100000)
params.add('c',   min=0,max = 100000)
```

```
from scipy.optimize import dual_annealing
# do fit, here with the default leastsq algorithm

minner = Minimizer(fit_msd2, params, fcn_args=(x, y))
print(minner)
result = minner.minimize(method="dual_annealing")
print(result)
# calculate final result
final = x + result.residual
#print(final)

# write error report
report_fit(result)
```

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))
ax.grid()
ax.set_ylabel('$\Delta_{msd}$(t) [$\mu$m]', fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel('Time Lag $\Delta t$ [s]', fontsize=18)
ax.loglog(x, y, label = 'Synthetic data')
ax.loglog(x, final, 'r-', linewidth=3,label='Fit')
ax.legend(loc='best', fontsize = 12)
```

[image: Graphical Fit results]

I believe the fit is not working properly and I cannot understand which are the reasons. Is there any library or check routing I can use in order to evaluate this?
If not, can someone suggest another way to perform this simulated annealing fit?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a link where the Furth formula is explained? What `A, B, c` do you get after fitting?

Comment: For the Furth formula you can take a look at Eq. 2: https://pagines.uab.cat/vmendez/sites/pagines.uab.cat.vmendez/files/72.pdf ,

Comment: Regarding the parameters of my fit: A=1.87, B=2.25, c=78977

Comment: Can you add plots of `(x,y)` with and without the normal noise? What happens if you fit without the normal noise? S.t. `y = Furth(A,B,a,x)`

Comment: Without the noise the fit still results very far away from what it should capture. I cannot plug in the comment images, I'll comment the post below

Comment: you can edit the original question to append the images :) My next suggestion will be a bit too large for the comment section, I will create an answer for my best guess.

Comment: you really, really need to give physically reasonable starting values for every parameter, and that starting value should not be at a boundary value.  Boundaries should be used to set physical limits.  Finally, while it can be useful to look at a plot of the fit, it is always (really, always) vital to look at the actual fit report.   Without the fit report you do not know what the fit did.

Comment: I am not really sure how in my particular case the fit report will be helpful. In this case I am just trying to play around with synthetic data in order to be able to later on guess the parameters for the experimental data. The latter are time-correlated between in each other though and classical statistic does not work anymore. Hence Chi-squared and others won't be reliable no more.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be to play around with the parameters of the optimizer. As it seems that your loss is too large, the optimizer currently accepts a solution too early. Since [lmfit](https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html) builds on [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html), it might be possible to pass the arguments of the optimizer as such:

```py
# [...]
opt_args = {
  maxiter=5000,  # originally 1000
  initial_tempfloat=7500  # originally 5230
  accept=-2.  # originally -5.0
}
minner = Minimizer(fit_msd2, params, fcn_args=(x, y))
result = minner.minimize(method="dual_annealing", **opt_args)
```

The above parametrization makes the optimizers more explorative, especially in the beginning of the optimization and lets it optimize for longer. A full list of the `dual_annealing` parameters can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html).

Does this lead to an improvement?

Also, I would suggest to use the square your error:

```
def fit_msd2(params, x, data):
    A = params['A']
    B = params['B']
    c = params['c']

    model = A*x + B * (np.exp(-c*x)-1) 
    return (model - data)**2  # or np.pow(model - data, 2), depending on data type
```

Comment: There are no improvements unfortunately. But thank you for the help!

Comment: You can also try to use the squared error. Besides that, I fail to see any errors in your code. Fiddling around with the optimizer might still be worth it, as it should essentially be able to find good values for the approximation.

Comment: I am just guessing that this fitting routine it is not able to go beyond the local minima of my function and I simply have to fit a more robust procedure to able able to solve the problem.